# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails tried it all

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS SpotifyClone;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS SpotifyClone;

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.plano (
    plano_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    plano_nome VARCHAR(512),
    plano_valor VARCHAR(512)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.pessoa_usuaria (
    pessoa_usuaria_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome_pessoa_usuaria VARCHAR(512),
    idade_pessoa_usuaria INT
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.assinatura (
    pessoa_usuaria_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    plano_id INT NOT NULL,
    data_assinatura DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_usuaria_id) REFERENCES pessoa_usuaria (pessoa_usuaria_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (plano_id) REFERENCES plano (plano_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.plano_pessoa_usuaria (
    pessoa_usuaria_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    plano_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_usuaria_id) REFERENCES pessoa_usuaria (pessoa_usuaria_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (plano_id) REFERENCES plano (plano_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.album (
    album_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    album_nome VARCHAR(512),
    album_ano_lancamento INT
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.cancao (
    cancao_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cancao_nome VARCHAR(512),
    cancao_duracao INT
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.artista (
    artista_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    artista_nome VARCHAR(512)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.album_cancao (
    album_id INT NOT NULL,
    cancao_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (album_id, cancao_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album (album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cancao_id) REFERENCES cancao (cancao_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.artista_album (
    artista_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    album_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (artista_id) REFERENCES artista (artista_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album (album_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.seguidores_artistas (
    artista_id INT NOT NULL,
    pessoa_usuaria_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (artista_id, pessoa_usuaria_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artista_id) REFERENCES artista (artista_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_usuaria_id) REFERENCES pessoa_usuaria (pessoa_usuaria_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.historico_reproducoes (
    id_reproducao INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    data_reproducao VARCHAR(512),
    pessoa_usuaria_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_usuaria_id) REFERENCES pessoa_usuaria (pessoa_usuaria_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SpotifyClone.cancao_historico_reproducoes (
    id_reproducao INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    cancao_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_reproducao) REFERENCES historico_reproducoes (id_reproducao),
    FOREIGN KEY (cancao_id) REFERENCES cancao (cancao_id)
);

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.plano (plano_id, plano_nome, plano_valor) VALUES
    ('1', 'gratuito', '0'),
    ('2', 'familiar', '7,99'),
    ('3', 'universitário', '5,99'),
    ('4', 'pessoal', '6,99');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.pessoa_usuaria (pessoa_usuaria_id, nome_pessoa_usuaria, idade_pessoa_usuaria) VALUES
    ('1', 'Barbara Liskov', '82'),
    ('2', 'Robert Cecil Martin', '58'),
    ('3', 'Ada Lovelace', '37'),
    ('4', 'Martin Fowler', '46'),
    ('5', 'Sandi Metz', '58'),
    ('6', 'Paulo Freire', '19'),
    ('7', 'Bell Hooks', '26'),
    ('8', 'Christopher Alexander', '85'),
    ('9', 'Judith Butler', '45'),
    ('10', 'Jorge Amado', '58');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.assinatura (pessoa_usuaria_id, plano_id, data_assinatura) VALUES
    ('1', '1', '2019-10-20'),
    ('2', '1', '2017-01-06'),
    ('3', '2', '2017-12-30'),
    ('4', '2', '2017-01-17'),
    ('5', '2', '2018-04-29'),
    ('6', '3', '2018-02-14'),
    ('7', '3', '2018-01-05'),
    ('8', '4', '2019-06-05'),
    ('9', '4', '2020-05-13'),
    ('10', '4', '2017-02-17');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.plano_pessoa_usuaria (pessoa_usuaria_id, plano_id) VALUES
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '1'),
    ('3', '2'),
    ('4', '2'),
    ('5', '2'),
    ('6', '3'),
    ('7', '3'),
    ('8', '4'),
    ('9', '4'),
    ('10', '4');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.album (album_id, album_nome, album_ano_lancamento) VALUES
    ('1', 'Renaissance', '2022'),
    ('2', 'Jazz', '1978'),
    ('3', 'Hot Space', '1982'),
    ('4', 'Falso Brilhante', '1998'),
    ('5', 'Vento de Maio', '2001'),
    ('6', 'QVVJFA?', '2003'),
    ('7', 'Somewhere Far Beyond', '2007'),
    ('8', 'I Put A Spell On You', '2012');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.artista (artista_id, artista_nome) VALUES
    ('1', 'Beyoncé'),
    ('2', 'Queen'),
    ('3', 'Elis Regina'),
    ('4', 'Baco Exu do Blues'),
    ('5', 'Blind Guardian'),
    ('6', 'Nina Simone');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.seguidores_artistas (artista_id, pessoa_usuaria_id) VALUES
    ('1', '1'),
    ('1', '2'),
    ('1', '6'),
    ('2', '1'),
    ('2', '3'),
    ('2', '10'),
    ('3', '1'),
    ('3', '2'),
    ('3', '9'),
    ('4', '4'),
    ('5', '5'),
    ('6', '6'),
    ('6', '7');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.cancao (cancao_id, cancao_nome, cancao_duracao) VALUES
    ('1', 'BREAK MY SOUL', '279'),
    ('2', 'VIRGO\'S GROOVE', '369'),
    ('3', 'ALIEN SUPERSTAR', '116'),
    ('4', 'Don\'t Stop Me Now', '203'),
    ('5', 'Under Pressure', '152'),
    ('6', 'Como Nossos Pais', '105'),
    ('7', 'O Medo de Amar é o Medo de Ser Livre', '207'),
    ('8', 'Samba em Paris', '267'),
    ('9', 'The Bard\'s Song', '244'),
    ('10', 'Feeling Good', '100');
    
INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.album_cancao (album_id, cancao_id) VALUES
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '1'),
    ('3', '1'),
    ('4', '2'),
    ('5', '3'),
    ('6', '4'),
    ('7', '5'),
    ('8', '6'),
    ('9', '7'),
    ('10', '8');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.artista_album (artista_id, album_id) VALUES
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '2'),
    ('4', '3'),
    ('5', '3'),
    ('6', '4'),
    ('7', '5'),
    ('8', '6');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.historico_reproducoes (id_reproducao, data_reproducao, pessoa_usuaria_id) VALUES
    ('1', '2022-02-28 10:45:55', '1'),
    ('2', '2020-05-02 05:30:35', '1'),
    ('3', '2020-03-06 11:22:33', '1'),
    ('4', '2022-08-05 08:05:17', '2'),
    ('5', '2020-01-02 07:40:33', '2'),
    ('6', '2020-11-13 16:55:13', '3'),
    ('7', '2020-12-05 18:38:30', '3'),
    ('8', '2021-08-15 17:10:10', '4'),
    ('9', '2022-01-09 01:44:33', '5'),
    ('10', '2020-08-06 15:23:43', '5'),
    ('11', '2017-01-24 00:31:17', '6'),
    ('12', '2017-10-12 12:35:20', '6'),
    ('13', '2011-12-15 22:30:49', '7'),
    ('14', '2012-03-17 14:56:41', '8'),
    ('15', '2022-02-24 21:14:22', '9'),
    ('16', '2015-12-13 08:30:22', '10');

INSERT INTO SpotifyClone.cancao_historico_reproducoes (id_reproducao, cancao_id) VALUES
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '1'),
    ('3', '1'),
    ('4', '2'),
    ('5', '2'),
    ('6', '3'),
    ('7', '3'),
    ('8', '4'),
    ('9', '5'),
    ('10', '5'),
    ('11', '6'),
    ('12', '6'),
    ('13', '7'),
    ('14', '8'),
    ('15', '9'),
    ('16', '10');
```

> `` Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SpotifyClone`.`album_cancao`, CONSTRAINT `album_cancao_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `album` (`album_id`)) ``

I tried to switch the album_cancao and artista_album orders as the INSERT INTO positions, but nothing works.

Comment: Clearly when pinned down & clearly expressed this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: What do you think this has to do with DB normalization?

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting into album_cancao you are using album_id values that don’t exist in the album table